# Grammarly and Overleaf: Is there a version of, or options in, detex that can leave some content between the latex marks?

Tags: overleaf, detex

I use Grammarly regularly, but as other questions have addressed, it can it does not work with Overleaf.  So my process is to use DeTex to strip the latex file, then a script to remove things like blank lines, spaces before periods and commas, etc.  Then edit on the desktop.

But one problem is that when there are latex data that would otherwise leave the sentence make sense, so stripped completely.

For example:

In \cite{xyz), we see that...and we are able to modify $x$ and $y$ appropriately.

This comes out

In, we see that .... to modify and appropriately.

Is there a way to put a constant in some way so that we would get:

In X, we see.... to modify X and X appropriately?  At least this would pass Grammarly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

There are two unofficial plugins you could try that might help you do this more easily than running your text through detex:

1. Writefull for Overleaf: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/writefull-for-overleaf/edhnemgfcihjcpfhkoiiejgedkbefnhg

   This plugin provides a similar type of language checker, that works by highlighting words and suggesting changes directly within the Overleaf editor.
2. Textarea: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overleaf-textarea/iejmieihafhhmjpoblelhbpdgchbckil

   This plugin puts your manuscript text into a textarea, which Grammarly can then parse to provide suggestions.

Please note that these are external plugins (use at your own discretion), and neither of these is officially provided by or supported by Overleaf, although we have worked with the Writefull team to help provide feedback on earlier versions of their plugin.

In the longer term we are working on an update to the Overleaf editor to make it easier to use grammar/language checkers like Writefull and Grammarly directly within the editor.

Comment: The Writefull for Overleaf extension is created and maintained by the official.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like as of July 2022, Overleaf is working on a solution to enable using Grammarly in their editor.

Source: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Use_Grammarly_with_Overleaf